# Making OsmDroid city label text larger

Tags: android, osmdroid

I find the text/labels for cities and towns to be rather small. Is there anyway i can manipulate the text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Osmdroid works with tiles that are static PNG images. You can not change the tile images. If you want to have a better mapping solution try MapsForge. This app/library works with maps data and renders them dynamically. This way you have more control on rendering maps and you can customize its texts and fonts and colors.

Take a look at this:
[Streetnames openstreetmaps more readable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883653/streetnames-openstreetmaps-more-readable-on-android)