# font size of maps in OSMDroid

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm trying to build an offline maps, with OSMDroid.
I have downloaded the tiles using MOBAC from Google maps, OpenStreetMap and Bing Maps.
The problem with all of them is the writing on the maps (street names, etc.) are too small to read.
I know this procedure downloads png file formats for the map tiles and it is not possible to increase the font size, but what I'm thinking is that for example, Google Maps Application (using its own API) is using the tiles from it's server, and they have a better font size in a same device. 
So is it possible to somehow download those tiles instead of what MOBAC downloads (which appears to be for a desktop version)?

this question is not a duplicate of these :

[Making OsmDroid city label text larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575102/making-osmdroid-city-label-text-larger)
[Streetnames openstreetmaps more readable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883653/streetnames-openstreetmaps-more-readable-on-android)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this code somewhere in the net, unfortunately can not remember where.

Any way the answer is here: in the `512` ...
I have downloaded my map tiles in SD resolution, (Not HD) which has the size of 256*256 px
But I introduced it to the TileSource as 512px ... what happens is it got scaled, and now the font size is readable on new devices with higher resolution.

keep in mind though you may wanna check the resolution before doing this hack as if the resolution of the device is too low, this may result into a very big font size !

```
final MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Google Terrian",
                ResourceProxy.string.bing, 10, 17, 512, ".jpg", new String[] {
                "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));
```

Be Aware that, changing this will result into a problem displaying the route using OsmBonusPack

Answer (score 6):

We have added support for dpi scaling to osmdroid 4.3.

```
mMapView.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
```

See also [issue #81](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/81).

Answer (score 1):

You may check the font size problem for OSMDroid here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/osmdroid/font/osmdroid/zgDHJGhJ62Q/dB2BrqXEofsJ

If you have other question, you can ask here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/osmdroid

Also you can get the source code here:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [MapBox Android](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk). This is a fork from osmdroid, and I think they worked on this issue about high-density screens.